# How to cache only selected documents in Firebase Firestore in JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a chat app and I want Firebase Firestore database to cache only that messages which are sent by me or for me. How can I do this?
Can I control what documents are cached in Firestore database? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore SDK provides no direct control over the cache, other than its total size, and whether or not it's active. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) describes everything you can do.

One alternative is to only use the SDK to read documents that should be cached, and use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) for all other reads that should not be cached.